# Do I need to transform/standardise my dependent variable?

Tags: regression, least-squares, outliers, heteroscedasticity, standardization

Attached are the results and the residual plot for my regression of control variables on CEO compensation (TDC1). When I look at the plot my main concerns are the outliers (which I checked to be correct without sufficient reason to exclude) and heteroskedasticity. Would it be advised to standardise my dependent variable in this case or should I use a different regression method. The data is panel data over the past ten years and the independent variables include firm specific, individual and period effects.

reg TDC1 Male Tenure Age i.Industry Assets NetIncomeLoss Sales i.Year i.nState

[image: Regression results]

[image: residual plot]

reg logCPIAdjTDC1 Male Tenure Age i.Industry L.Assets L.NetIncomeLoss L.Sales i.Year i.nState

[image: residual plot logged inflation adjusted]

xtreg CPIAdjustedTDC1 Male Tenure Age i.Industry L.Assets L.NetIncomeLoss L.Sales i.Year i.nState if TDC1 < 60000

[image: GLS]

Comment: Your data spans more than 10 years. Did you convert the outcome to say 2021 dollars, in order to make the compensation numbers comparable?

Comment: I did not. What exactly do you mean? I only included the year in the controls as a factor variable to control for period effects.

Comment: Because of inflation, the value of 1 dollar changes over time. That's why sometimes you hear "the price of X in 2000 dollars". 2000 is an example of course.

Comment: Got you, thanks for the input. I will add CPI as a variable, make a new compensation variable of TDC1/CPI(t) and try replot residuals. Do you reckon this could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe it's one issue. But your model fits very poorly. You can see that the predicted range is 0-60K. That's not wide enough range for many white-collar professions, let alone CEOs. The distribution of Y is very right skewed (as expected). Have you tried log-transforming Y, so that the effect of the predictors is multiplicative, not additive.

Comment: Where do you see the predicted range is 0 - 60k? This is the residuals right, not the predictions? Also TDC1 is in 1000's of $, so it would be 0 - 60mln. I'll also try logging TDC1.

Comment: I added the residuals after adjusting TDC1 for inflation and logging the values

Comment: I would also try a random forest (or another general tree-based ML algorithm). Regression assumes that the model is valid/specified correctly while you just want to see how accurately you can predict CEO compensation based on X predictors. The answer might be "not particularly accurately".

Comment: I also included residuals for a GLS regression, excluding salaries over 60 mln. The fit already looks a lot better. Only problem is I can't really justify excluding the outliers in theoretically. Anyways, thank you for trying to help solve the problem. Perhaps the outcome is the CEO salary can hardly be estimated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that CEO pay is a non-negative financial quantity, it will generally make sense to examine it on a log-scale, as you have done in your second model.  (As some commentators have also pointed out, it is sensible to adjust for CPI to have a stable financial measure, which you appear to also have done in your second model.)  The residual plot for this second model looks mostly okay, but there is some evidence of nonlinearity and there are some clusters of large negative residuals.  In view of this, I would recommend that you examine the added variable plots for the model to see if you can identify any source of nonlinearity, and consider adding one or more higher-order terms for your explanatory variables.  I would also recommend you manually examine the clusters of outliers to see if there is anything they have in common that might suggest a change in your model.

In relation to the clusters of outliers in the residual plot, note that these are not a significant problem in regression analysis so long as you are careful when making predictions on new data.  All these outliers mean is that your stipulated error distribution (the normal distribution) has tails that are too thin, which is not consistent with the evidence in the data.  If you were to generalise your error distribution for the model (e.g., to a [generalised normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution)) then you could accomodate the higher kurtosis exhibited in the residuals.  In order to form prediction intervals with new data you would need to be careful to ensure that your model can accomodate the residual kurtosis (and ideally also residual skew) but this is something that is achievable with some changes to your model.

Overall, I would say that you have quite a good starting point in your second model, with only a few small remaining issues that should be examined and accomodated with model changes.

Comment: Dear Ben, Thank you for the elaborate answer. It is very reaffirming to hear the new residual plots are a good step in the right direction! I will make sure to play around with the other advise you mention in your answer.